# Recovering past work with git after mistake

Tags: git, github

Let me preface this by saying that I am relatively new to git so I might have difficulty correctly expressing my situation.

I was doing some work on a project and I wanted to commit the changes I had made. I proceeded to run through the next few commands:

```
   git add .
   git commit -m "Finished user signup"
```

At this point, it appeared to process my commit and handled all the changes, insertions, and deletions. Then I proceeded with:

```
    git checkout master
```

It successfully switched to the master branch. I thought I had been in a branch at the time and I tried merging it, but that didn't work so I just moved forward. I pushed and everything was up to date. Then I made some quick changes to other files and tried:

```
    git commit -am "Add SSL in production"
```

It was successful. However, now all of my changes prior to this last commit are gone and I would really like to get them back if possible. I now realize that perhaps I need to take a step back and actually UNDERSTAND git rather than just running through the steps of the tutorial I'm following, but I really would love to get a mulligan on this one if possible. If you have any ideas how I can git my files back I could really use your help.

**Edit:** I tried looking at the log with "git log" and it doesn't show any sign of the commit I want to recover...

Comment: If you've successfully committed your changes in the other branch DON'T PANIC, probably you just didn't merged these changes in your master branch, it's not likely you'll lost something if you succefully committed you changes: git is there for this exact reason ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can understand you switched from the topic-branch to the master branch but you didn't merge the topic-branch's commits. You can do this using the git command merge or rebase:

```
# Be sure you're in the master branch, you should see a star before master
$git checkout master
$git branch
# Now take the commits from the topic-branch
$git rebase TOPIC_BRANCH_NAME
```

Using `$git log` you should be able now to see the other branch's commits.

Comment: After doing some more hunting around, I think you're correct. Thanks for the help.

Comment: ya, version control is nice. I just don't have a good enough grasp on git yet though. I think this ended up being a pretty decent learning process though.

Answer (score 1):

If the reason is committing your changes while not having a branch checked out, maybe you'll be able to track those missing commits with `git reflog`. The first column of its output lists fingerprints of commits among which you may find the ones you are looking for. After you find a specific commit you'd like to recover, say `abc123`, you can make a branch pointing to it by doing `git branch recovery abc123`.

Comment: After I make the branch, how can I restore the files? I did what you recommended but when I checked the status it said I was on the master branch and that there was nothing to commit.

Comment: You can `git checkout recovery` to switch to the newly created branch. Visualising the big picture using either `gitk --all` or `git log --all --graph --oneline --decorate` might also be helpful to see what's really happening with your branches.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to omit the last commit, if its do the following

```
git reset HEAD^1
```

It will omit the last head(commit)